# Java Minecraft Plugin EventHandler?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm making a server plugin that kicks players when they die. I've got that all sorted out, but I want to be able to toggle it on and off. I've seen to use a boolean, but it yells at me when I put @EventHandler inside of a one, I don't think I'm doing it right... So I guess the question is really, is there a way to make it so when "/kdoff" is executed, @EventHandler isn't until "/kd" is executed. I feel like there's something you can do with onDisable() but I'm not fully sure how those work to be honest.

```java
package me.Cats.KickDead;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin
    implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() { // on server start-up
        System.out.println("Death Kick is enabled");
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        
    }
    
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) { // enables command
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("kd")) {
            if (sender instanceof Player) { //player
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                if (player.hasPermission("kickdead.use")) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&bPlayers will now be sent to the &8&lShadow Realm&b. &r(&0&aOn&r)")); // Yu-gi-oh Reference
                
                return true;
                }
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cYour deck lacks the power to send someone to the &8&lShadow Realm&r&b.")); // Yet another Yu-gi-oh reference

            }
            
        if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("kdoff")) {
            if(sender instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                if (player.hasPermission("kickdead.use")) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&bPlayers will be allowed on the &a&lMoral Plane&r&b. &r(&0&4Off&r)")); // Yu-gi-oh Reference
                
                return false;
            }
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cYour deck lacks the power to allow people to walk this &a&lMoral Plane&r&b.")); 
        }
            
            
        else { //console
            sender.sendMessage("Currently only works if ran by a player. I'm a bit lazy..."); 
            return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    @EventHandler // if a player dies they're kicked
    public void onDeath(EntityDeathEvent event) {
        Player player = (Player)event.getEntity();
        player.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "You Died"); 
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You have `onEnable()` built into the framework, so there should be an enable method as well. Or an `enabled` property... whatever that listener is listening to.

Comment: nvm just read the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is just to store a boolean value somewhere for whether kick on death is enabled. The `/kd` and `/kdoff` commands can set it, and whenever somebody dies you just check if it is enabled to decide if they should be kicked.

`OnDisabled` is an event that is called when the plugin is disabled, generally meaning when the server shuts down (though there are other times as well!). You don't want to fully disable the plugin, because then you wouldn't be able to catch the `/kd` command.

```java
public class Main extends JavaPlugin
    implements Listener {
    public static boolean kickOnDeath = true;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() { // on server start-up
        if (kickOnDeath) {
            System.out.println("Death Kick is enabled");
        }
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        
    }
    
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) { // enables command
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("kd")) {
            if (sender instanceof Player) { //player
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                if (player.hasPermission("kickdead.use")) {
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&bPlayers will now be sent to the &8&lShadow Realm&b. &r(&0&aOn&r)")); // Yu-gi-oh Reference
                    kickOnDeath = true;
                    return true;
                }
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cYour deck lacks the power to send someone to the &8&lShadow Realm&r&b.")); // Yet another Yu-gi-oh reference
            } else { //console
                sender.sendMessage("Currently only works if ran by a player. I'm a bit lazy..."); 
                return true;
            }
        } else if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("kdoff")) {
            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                if (player.hasPermission("kickdead.use")) {
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&bPlayers will be allowed on the &a&lMoral Plane&r&b. &r(&0&4Off&r)")); // Yu-gi-oh Reference
                    kickOnDeath = false;
                    return true;
                }
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cYour deck lacks the power to allow people to walk this &a&lMoral Plane&r&b."));
            } else { //console
                sender.sendMessage("Currently only works if ran by a player. I'm a bit lazy..."); 
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    @EventHandler // if a player dies they're kicked
    public void onDeath(EntityDeathEvent event) {
        if (kickOnDeath) {
            Player player = (Player)event.getEntity();
            player.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "You Died"); 
        }
    }
    
}
```

This implementation has a global flag that just enables and disables, but I'm sure you could make it persistent or player-specific.

Comment: That's what I'm confused on, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Using a boolean is the way to go if you want to globally enable/disable the kicking on death event.

You just need to add it as a field to the class:

```java
public class Main extends JavaPlugin
    implements Listener {

    private boolean enabled = true; // Added this line.

    @Override
    public void onEnable() { // on server start-up
        System.out.println("Death Kick is enabled");
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        
    }

    ...
```

And now you can set the value of the `enabled` field when the commands are called:

```java
if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("kd")) {
    if (sender instanceof Player) { //player
      Player player = (Player) sender;
      if (player.hasPermission("kickdead.use")) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&bPlayers will now be sent to the &8&lShadow Realm&b. &r(&0&aOn&r)")); // Yu-gi-oh Reference
        
        enabled = true; // Added this line to set the enable flag.

        return true;
      }
      player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cYour deck lacks the power to send someone to the &8&lShadow Realm&r&b.")); // Yet another Yu-gi-oh reference
    }
    
else if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("kdoff")) {
    if(sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
      if (player.hasPermission("kickdead.use")) {
          player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&bPlayers will be allowed on the &a&lMoral Plane&r&b. &r(&0&4Off&r)")); // Yu-gi-oh Reference
          
          enabled = false; // Added this line to set the enable flag.

          return false;
      }
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cYour deck lacks the power to allow people to walk this &a&lMoral Plane&r&b.")); 
}
```

Now you can check the value of the `enabled` field in your `onDeath` listener and act accordingly:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onDeath(EntityDeathEvent event) {
   if (enabled) {
       // Kill player.
   }
}
```

Comment: the if for the `/kdoff` needed to be an else if

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I should've proofread your code a bit more before copying it and adding in the solution.

Comment: No worries, gave me a little bit of a challenge to debug the code by looking at them both and seeing what was wrong. They're both the same thing, but I liked the `kickOnDeath` Kai had. Cheers though! Edit: Not like I misspelled "Mortal" twice after catching it written as Moral, then Motral... Dyslexic & Coding don't get along.